# Jogar dados para uma box

Tags: javascript

Necessito pegar os dados de um input e passar a uma box!
 Tenho um cod que pega os dados de uma combo para jogar em uma box!

cod:

```
function move(Origem, Destino)
{
    var opt = document.createElement("option"); 

    for(i = 0; i < Origem.options.length; i++)
    {
        if (Origem.options[i].selected && Origem.options[i].value != "")
        {
            if(w_seq_qtde[Origem.options[i].value]==0)
                alert("sem periférico no estoque!");
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("cb_MenuDestino").options.add(opt);
                opt.text = Origem.options[i].text;
                opt.value = Origem.options[i].value;
                w_seq_qtde[Origem.options[i].value]--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

input:

```
<input type="text" name="tx_MenuOrigem" value="">
```

button :

```
<input type="button" onClick="move(this.form.tx_MenuOrigem,this.form.cb_MenuDestino)" value="+++">
```

select:

```
<select multiple size="7" name="cb_MenuDestino" style="width:300"></select>
```

Nesse caso quando se seleciona o item na combo e aperta em um button para add ele joga na box! Mas quero pegar os dados em um input e jogar dentro da box! Se possivel tem como ser mais ou menos parecido para melhor entendimento?! Obrigado a quem ajudar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function move(input, Destino)
{
 var opt = document.createElement("option"); 
 var valor = input.value;
 if(valor=="")
 return;

  if(valor==0)
  { 
    alert("sem periférico no estoque!"); 
   return;
  }            

  opt.text = valor ;
  opt.value = valor ;
  Destino.options.add(opt);

 }
```

Comment: quero bloquear caso os dados forem iguais ao inserido, como faço?

Comment: Pode explicar como a sua resposta soluciona o problema?

Comment: function JaExiste(Destino, valor)
{

for(i = 0; i < Destino.options.length; i++)
    {
        if (Destino.options[i].value == valor)
                   return true;
     }
return false;
}

function move(input, Destino)
{
 var opt = document.createElement("option"); 
 var valor = input.value;
 if(valor==""|| JaExiste(Destino,valor)) return;

  if(valor==0)
  { 
    alert("sem periférico no estoque!"); 
   return;
  }            

  opt.text = valor ;
  opt.value = valor ;
  Destino.options.add(opt);

 }

Answer (score 1):

Verificar se o valor já existe

```
function JaExiste(Destino, valor)
{

for(i = 0; i < Destino.options.length; i++)
    {
        if (Destino.options[i].value == valor)
                   return true;
     }
return false;
}
```

Adicionar o valor no select

```
function move(input, Destino)
{
//Obtém o valor digitado 
 var valor = input.value;

 //retorna se não houver valor ou se o valor já existir no destino

 if(valor==""|| JaExiste(Destino,valor)) return;

//Mensagem do explo caso o valor seja 0
  if(valor==0)
  { 
    alert("sem periférico no estoque!"); 
   return;
  }        
  var opt = document.createElement("option"); 
  opt.text = valor ;
  opt.value = valor ;
  Destino.options.add(opt);
 }
```